# Spoiled schema after one week using

Tags: ios, backend, stackmob

Resuming my posts(http://support.stackmob.com/entries/24775522-iOS-SDK-2-0-0-relation..., [iOS Stackmob SDK(2.0.0) (relationships) Bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17594149/ios-stackmob-sdk2-0-0-r)..., https://github.com/stackmob/stackmob-ios-sdk/issues/51).

Everything work perfect within a week. Then something happens on server side and any relationship aren't work via ios SDK. I need to remove schema(for example I can't remove "User" as can be clearly understood) for repair. Or I need to create new account/application for resolving issue. It is subject to the development schemas only(on the production I have no tested).

Crash logs are different. Sometimes like this(http://support.stackmob.com/entries/24775522-iOS-SDK-2-0-0-relation...), sometimes just assembler code, without any descriptions in log.

Comment: You need to describe the specific problem. Also you did not comment on or accept the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17594149/ios-stackmob-sdk2-0-0-r